# Get all the text after the dash: -

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to extract any text after the underscore including the underscore

For example, `Segment_Name` needs to become `Segment`

[image: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsCFJ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsCFJ.png)]

```
SELECT 
    s.segment_name,
    LTRIM(SUBSTRING(s.segment_name, LEN(s.segment_name) - 7, LEN(s.segment_name))) AS Segment
FROM 
    [prod_idw_mart].[t].[dim_segment] s
```

This works as such except that the -7 is too short.

As the example below shows, there is no specific length I can assign. Therefore, I was looking for a universal solution.

I tried:

```
    SELECT 
        s.segment_name,
        RIGHT(s.segment_name, CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(s.segment_name)) - 1) AS S
    FROM 
        [prod_idw_mart].[timesheet].[dim_segment] s
```

But I get this error:

> Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function.

Instead of -1, I tried > 0, but it does not like that at all:

> Incorrect syntax near '>'.

Comment: Some of your data doesn't have a dash in it. So you'll get a 0 with the `INSTR` then subtract 1 to get a negative value. You can't have a negative value for the `RIGHT` function. Use a `CASE` statement to check for dashes first.

Comment: Looks like you have multiple special characters to look for.. like a comma, a dash a colon , semi colon and what not. You need to use pat index to figure out special characters and then get anything to the right of the special character.. if none found, return nothing

Comment: Please do not post image, post the sample data and expected result as formatted text. Also looks like your requirement is not only `dash` but multiple characters. Please edit and update your question

Comment: When asking a question you need to ensure that the sample and required result are correct. How does `Execution: Traini` end up as `Training` ? Are you supposed to also have some logic to auto complete the word ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @delms varchar(20)='%[-,:]%';

select 
     segment_name
    ,case when PATINDEX(@delms, segment_name)=0 
        then '' 
        else substring(segment_name, 1+PATINDEX(@delms, segment_name), len(segment_name)) 
    end as segment
from @table_name
```

Comment: absolutely excellent!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
select Segment_Name,
  trim
  (
    right
    (
      translate(Segment_Name, ',:','--'),
      len(Segment_Name) - iif(charindex('-', translate(Segment_Name, ',:','--'))>0, 
                              charindex('-', translate(Segment_Name, ',:','--')), 
                              len(Segment_Name)
                             )
    )
  ) as Segment
from table_name
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZC98bAzY)

Note:

This supposes only one delimiter in the string.
For the translate function, you may add extra delimiters to the ',:' list, and if your version of SQL Server doesn't support this function you may use multiple replace functions instead.

Comment: Excellent, for sql I used 'replace' instead of 'translate'. But works nicely. Thank you.